# Displaying converted string to number using console.log or document.write not working. Concatenation display not working not working either

Tags: javascript, html, type-conversion, console.log, document.write

I'm a beginner in JS and HTML and this program was for learning the concepts better. Trying out a basic program to convert a string to num in 3 ways. Unable to determine if the conversion has happened. Also unable to display concatenation of two such converted numbers.

The errors are thrown at lines consisting of console.log and document.write.
Error:Uncaught Syntax Error: Illegal Character

What is the issue here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h6>Q3</h6>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      numstr = "456";
      let num1 = numstr – 0;
      let num2 = parseInt(numstr);
      let num3 = new Number(numstr);
      console.log(typeof(num1));
      console.log(typeof(num2));
      console.log(typeof(num3));

    </script>
<br>
    <h6>Q4</h6>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var num = 123.789;
        num2 = parseInt( num );
        num3 = parseInt( num, 8);
        console.log(num2 + “:::” + num3);
        document.write(num2 + “:::” + num3);
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you copied and pasted it from some document.
minus in **let num1 = numstr – 0;** is not a minus, but end dash symbol.
Also replace quotes in “:::” into ":::"

Comment: Oh yes. That's what I did. It works perfectly now. Thank you